# imagick issue: postscript delegate failed

Tags: web, webserver, imagemagick, imagick

I am looking to get ImageMagick working with gs and imagick. I am trying to execute the line of code (which fetches the 1st line of a multi page/layer pdf to display it). This code shouldn't be the source of the error, it's a server side issue.

```
$img = new Imagick($pdf_file."[0]");
```

On the webpage in source, I get this error:

```
exception 'ImagickException' with message 'Postscript delegate failed...
```

I have done quite a bit of Googling / attempts to fix this. I have:

- Reinstalled gs and ImageMagick (currently imagick is giving me a bizarre make error due to the fact that I am using the RC rather than the stable)
- Added the extension to php.ini (imagick.so)
- Re-configured the ImageMagick installation to include --with-gslib (gs is added to the list)
- Dynamically linked /usr/bin's (for gs)
- A few other things (yes, they are all available and installed).

The convert command DOES work, I have tested and confirmed it's usage with the following line which runs fine with no errors. The resulting PDF displays perfectly.

```
convert test.pdf test2.pdf
```

I've exhausted nearly everything I can think of, and most of what Google and other sites have to offer. Does anyone have any advice on the best way to approach this? I'm glad to produce logs and such, just not sure exactly what would help with this error.

Comment: You need to add a few more info if you want us to go beyond mere speculation. (1) What kind of conversion do you want to achieve. (2) What file type is your input? (3) What file type is your wanted output? (4) What type of parameters do you use for your conversion process?

Answer (score 1):

I'm a bit suspicious about the message mentioning the *PostScript* delegate, while you are processing *PDF*... Are you sure you did indeed feed PDF, not PostScript to your ImageMagick process.

In a **first** stage to debug this, you should add the `-verbose` parameter to any ImageMagick command you are running. This will show you (at least) which exact commandline IM uses to call Ghostscript. Then you can run this GS command manually to see what kind of more error messages you may get. Next, you could run this GS command, but with an added `-dDEBUG` to harvest even more info.

In a **second** stage of debugging, you could add `-debug configure`, `-debug trace` and `-debug all` (which may or may not give you additional clues if you know how to interprete the info printed)... especially if you compare with the output of `convert -list delegate`.

Comment: going to give these a shot in a little, I'll report back